# How do I create an interface that takes a symbol index in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to create an interface for an object that returns subobjects with string indices, and a string name with a symbol interface. I tried the following:

```
const $name = Symbol.for('name')

interface Foo {
  [key: string] : Foo
  [name: $name] : string
}
```

However, I get the error: `An index signature must be a string or a number`. But ... its not true that indexes must be strings or numbers, at least for modern javascript versions? How can I declare my object or work around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed in Typescript (4.9):

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44512

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9/

Answer (score 3):

It seems that at the moment you can not do this for custom symbols (unless I'm misreading the thread). This is a known issue and is being tracked as https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1863

Comment: it just took five years to fix it  :-)

Answer (score 1):

A temporary workaround, if you have a small number of symbols you want to use, is to add them to the `SymbolConstructor` interface in your `globals.d.ts` file, and then set them in your code:

```
// globals.d.ts
interface SymbolConstructor {
    $name: symbol;
}

// code.ts
const $name = Symbol.for('name');
Symbol.$name = $name;

interface Foo {
  [key: string] : Foo
  [Symbol.$name] : string
}
```